# in Alert can variables be concatenated into a message string?

Tags: react-native

I have a quick question that I think I may know the answer to already but was trying to confirm from the SO community of RN devs.

Example, I was wondering if I could concatenate a variable like say "product" into an Alert message?

```
        const genericFn = (id) => {
        Alert.alert('are you sure?', 'Do you really want to delete'+ product + ' ?', [
        {text: 'no',style: 'default'},
        {text: 'Yes',style: 'destructive', .../
```

where the variable product, from another array could be mixed into the message string. Is that possible with the Alert API or is something like Modal needed here?
Just wondering, and I had not seen anything definitively addressing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, here is the code :

```
const product = "Hello World";



Alert.alert(
      "Alert Title " + product,
      "My Alert Msg",
      [
        {
          text: "Ask me later",
          onPress: () => console.log("Ask me later pressed")
        },
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
      ]
    );
```

Comment: interesting. So could it also be added as the second part of the alert? i.e. -  "My Alert Msg" + product, ?

Comment: Yeah you can do it.